# Import Inkscape text to Scribus

Tags: inkscape, scribus

When I import an Inkscape file into Scribus the text is always vectorized. Is there a way to import editable text into Scribus from Inkscape?

Comment: What is your current workflow and what format are you using for the import?

Comment: I'm primarily designing in Inkscape and using Scribus for CMYK color editing. I've tried several formats for import - SVG, PDF, EPS.

Comment: did the answer I gave work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Given the choice I'd never lay out body text in an Inkscape file destined for output via Scribus as Scribus handles this sort of text so much better.

That said, if you've inherited the files or there's some other compelling reason behind your question then using pdf as the intermediate file *might* work.

In Inkscape's Save As pdf dialogue there's a "Convert text to paths" check box which should be left unselected and Scribus should happily open the resultant pdf with editable text.

Along the way you may have issues with fonts but it'll work by and large.

If you've got the choice though I'd recommend letting Scribus handle the text and leaving Inkscape to provide your vector components in svg format.

Comment: Hi Matt, experiencing the same issue, I just came across your answer. Though I'll take your advice to heart to use Scribus for text, I can't seem to import editable text from Inkscape into Scribus. I tried various formats, all from ps, eps, pdf, and plain svg, and where applicable not selecting the "convert text to paths" checkbox. But Scribus still keeps converting the text to paths.

Comment: @vic Same computer running both apps? Did you draw the Inkscape text boxes as rectangles or simply click and type? If you're transforming the text it might never work as expected. If you're using a "fancy" font try a version with a standard (arial etc.) font. Hth

Comment: Actually, I didn't create the text in Inkscape at all. I imported an ai-file from Illustrator, improved it a bit and then wanted to open it in Scribus in order to prepare for print. And yes, the fonts are "fancy" but they are installed on the system. I'll try as you suggested.

Comment: Would you please change ""might"" to "*might*". I'm pretty sure you're not quoting anyone or anything.